# How is managed deletion of K8s objects in skaffold deploy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, skaffold

I am starting to play with `skaffold` to handle continuous deployment in my Kubernetes cluster.

I have a bunch of yaml files that just wait to be applied with `kubectl`, at one point `a.yaml` and `b.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta29
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: skaffold-deploy
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - a.yaml
    - b.yaml
```

Now, I make a development that needs to **delete** objects (in terms of `kubectl delete`) described in `b.yaml` (and I simply removed the file in my directory)

Is it possible to do so with `skaffold`?

If I `skaffold deploy` with this `skaffold.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta29
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: skaffold-deploy
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - a.yaml
```

objects in `b.yaml` are not deleted nor updated.

I was looking for a way to do this in the official documentation but could not find anything related to it. `skaffold delete` seems to delete everything that was previously deployed with it.

Thanks a lot in advance